# How to capture dynamic value from Response Headers in Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, loadrunner

I figured out the dynamics values which is nonce and state [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv5wJ.png).

These dynamic values are in Response data under Response headers in the URL  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhDla.png).

I tried to capture using Regular Expression Extractor and Boundary Expresssion Extractor  but still it shows nothing. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnkgH.png)

Could anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

RegExp tester mode of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener only works with **response data**, you're being redirected therefore there is no response data hence it shows blank value and you will not be able to validate the regular expression.

The options are in:

1. Either copy response headers to [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-dummy-sampler) which allows testing your PostProcessors without hitting the system under test
2. Or Configure Regular Expression Extractor to look into Response Headers (and most probably to sub-samples) and add [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) or [PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) to see what was extracted.

   [image]